# How to locate Venue Map using eventbrite Api in other app

Tags: eventbrite

I'm trying to integrate eventbrite's events in my app. I want to locate Event's venue map and not able to fetch venue map's image from any eventbrite's api.
Anyone have idea?
thanks!

Comment: Provide the code you've tried..

Comment: I just want to know that they(Event brite) have used longitude and latitude to show venue map or map image is store somewhere(if store,api to get venue map image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventbrite uses the venue's latitude and longitude to call the Google Maps API and get the map, thus it's not stored by EB and cannot be retrieved via the API. You can call the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=en) and retrieve it yourself though.